# A way for iterable zip like single element for Python

Tags: python

Hi guys I just want to know if there's a way to iterate over a tuple that behaves like zip.

For example:

```
zipper = zip(['aye', 'bee'], ['ex', 'why'])
for x, y in zipper:
    print(x, y)
aye ex
bee why

tupl = 3, 2
for x, y in tupl:
    print(x, y)
# 'int' object is not iterable.
```

What I knew now is that it can't be zip-ed:

```
tupl = zip(3, 2)
# zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

I am trying to pass zipper into a function, I also hope to pass the tuple or a single set of zip.

```
def processthis(zipper):
    for x, y in zipper:
        # do something with x and y
```

Comment: what's your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a loop of `for x, y in tupl:` you are expecting `tupl` to be a sequence of tuples, rather than a tuple.

If you want your loop to process only one tuple you should assign `tupl` with `[(3, 2)]` instead of `(3, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are missing.

When passing a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to function, it needs to be wrapped by parenthesis.

In your case,

```
zip((3, 2), (4, 5))  # zipping 2 tuples
```

Otherwise, zip will sees 3 and 2 as two positional arguments.